# Passing youtube video to facebook like iframe link in fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox for displaying videos on popup, also facebook like button on title.

```
<a class="fancybox-media change_status" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo" title="sa">Youtube</a>
```

---

```
$('.fancybox-media')
    .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
    .fancybox({
    href: $(this).attr('href'),
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    autoDimensions: false,
    padding: [15, 15, 0, 15],

    height: 370,
    width: 490,

    arrows: false,
    helpers: {
        media: {},
        buttons: {},
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },

    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {

            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    }
});
```

Problem occuring in `this.href` tag, error showing "The href URL must be absolute on FB".

Comment: try to `console.log` the this.href and run the full url in the browser to check what it does. Facebook might have issues with the entity replacement (&amp;).

Comment: Thanks, Fixed previous passing without http: